# I'm having problems reading a csv file and inserting the words into a text box in pyqt. The words are not printing into the textbox like they should

Tags: python-3.x

This is the modules that are needed.

```
import sys
import csv
from csv import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

qtCreatorFile = "Inquiry.ui" # Enter file here.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

     Hebrew =  {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,\
               'j':600,'k':10,'l':20,'m':30,'n':40,'o':50,'p':60,'q':70,'r':80,\
               's':90,'t':100,'u':200,'v':700,'w':900,'x':300,'y':400,'z':500}
```

Some other code that is important to help reproduce the problem:

Create the GUI:

```
    def __init__(self):
        "Create UI"
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnCalculate.clicked.connect(self.Calculate)

    def Calculate(self):
```

The Event:

```
        try:
            Event = str(self.txtInquiry)
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

The Word Text File Path:

```
        y = 'C:/Users/Jacob-C/Documents/words_alpha.txt'
```

These are the functions used.

Calculates the value of each word from the key mappings in the gematria system used.

```
         def gematric_value(x, L):
            value = 0
            for v in x.lower():
                try:
                    value = value + L[v]
                except KeyError:
                    pass
            return value
```

Modulo Function used heavily in integer reduction.

```
        def MOD_CALC(x, y):
            return (x % y)
```

This function takes a number and integer reduces it.

```
        def Check_Value(x):
            if x > 9 and MOD_CALC(x, 9) == 0:
                return (MOD_CALC(x, 9) + 9)
            elif x > 9 and MOD_CALC(x, 9) != 0:
                return MOD_CALC(x, 9)
            else:
                return x
```

This is the function that does not insert the words into the plain textbox.

```
    def Gematria(f, Hebrew, EN):
```

opens text file and converts it to a csv file. Then reads each word in the text file and compares the gematric value of the word and the gematric value of the event. If they match, the word is inserted to the plain text box on the qt form. This function does not do what is intended. Instead it doesn't insert anything into the plain text box.

```
         with open(f, 'r', newline='') as input_file_name:
                input_file = csv.reader(input_file_name, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
                for word in input_file:
                    GV = Check_Value(gematric_value(word, L))
                    if GV == EN:
                        self.txtWords.insertPlainText(", ".join(word))
```

Integer reduces the Event Number

```
        HN = gematric_value(Event, Hebrew) # Hebrew Event Number
        MOD_HN = Check_Value(HN) # Reduced Hebrew Event Number
```

The Call:

```
        Gematria(y, Hebrew, MOD_HN)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jacob-C\Documents\Numerology_Predict.py", line 146, in <module>
    Launch_Program()
  File "C:\Users\Jacob-C\Documents\Numerology_Predict.py", line 144, in Launch_Program
    Gematria(y, L, EN)
  File "C:\Users\Jacob-C\Documents\Numerology_Predict.py", line 116, in Gematria
    GV = Check_Value(Event_Number(word, L))
  File "C:\Users\Jacob-C\Documents\Numerology_Predict.py", line 95, in Event_Number
    for e in E.lower():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Does the code not do what you want? What does it do instead? Why did you not change it so that it does what you want?

Comment: Your code blurb with `input_file` and `csv_file` is a little strange and is probably the source of your trouble. For debugging purposes, you might want to add a print statement in your except clause so you know there was an error. The `for word in csv_file` will not work because in the line before you open it for writing. At that point, the csv_file will be empty.

Comment: So your question is now why you cannot use the `lower` method with a list?

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
   def Gematria(f, L, EN):
         with open(f, 'r') as input_file:
            for word in input_file:
               GV = Check_Value(Event_Number(word, L))
               if GV == EN:
                   print(word)
```